# unable to create domain in Weblogic Server

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

D:\NewWeblogicServer\oracle_common\common\bin>config.cmd

The system cannot find the file D:\NewWeblogicServer\oui\bin...globalEnv.properties.

ERROR: Unable to locate property "JAVA_HOME" in properties file D:\NewWeblogicServer\oui\bin...globalEnv.properties

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but I was facing the same problem, in my machine there are numerous Weblogic 12c installations and end up picking the wrong one. In this case, the file '.globalEnv.properties' existed in the directory '[WEBLOGIC_HOME]\oui', but when attempting to read it, Windows prompted the error: "Can not open file [WEBLOGIC_HOME]\oui.globalEnv.properties". I am assuming that this installation was done for another user, and attempting to assign permissions for my user, IT end up half way through, because in close inspection the whole directory was missing some files and folders, so it was no use to me.

Once I end up in the right Weblogic, I verified that the file '.globalEnv.properties' existed and can be opened, containing the JAVA_HOME property with correct value, and was able to create the domain without any issue.

So, in my experience, this error is due to some corrupt installation/use, or the installation was done for another user, and you must restore permissions to the new user.